# Change the value of the key in dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list called 'li':

```
dict1={1:'1 okt 2002'}
dict2={1:'2 may 2003'}
li=[dict1,dict2]
```

I want to change the dates to python date_time format, Python understand 'Oct' not 'Okt'. So I decided to replace 'Okt' by 'Oct' first. I have tried

```
In[1]: A=[]
        for item in li:
           a=item[1].split()
           replace(a,'okt', 'oct')
           A.append(a)
        A
out[1]: [['1', 'oct', '2002'], ['2', 'may', '2003']]
```

But this is not exactly what I am looking for. Is there any way to turn
['1','oct','2002'] to '1 oct 2002'?

Or is it any better way to change 'Okt' to 'Oct' inside the dictionary values?
Thank you.

Replace function:

```
def replace(l, X, Y):
    for i,v in enumerate(l):
        if v == X:
            l.pop(i)
            l.insert(i, Y)
```

Comment: What does your `replace` function do? But yeah, you just need to `.join`

Comment: @alfasin join is not a function of lists

Comment: @meyer9 my python is a bit rusty, it's the other way around: `" ".join(['1', 'oct', '2002'])`

Comment: @alfasin no problem. doesn't really make sense

Comment: @meyer9 what doesn't make sense? if you refer to `join` being a function of a string I agree, it would make much more sense if it was a function of list :)

Comment: the fact that join runs on a string

Comment: But if `join` is a `str` method, it will work on *any* iterable.

Comment: that's true. and also the fact that it maintains the same type as the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to know why your code isn't working because we don't know what your `replace` function does, but apparently, it returns a list. Here's a quick way to achieve what you want, though:

```
>>> dict1={1:'1 okt 2002'}
>>> dict2={1:'2 may 2003'}
>>> li=[dict1,dict2]
>>> [{k:v.replace('okt','oct') for k,v in d.items()} for d in li]
[{1: '1 oct 2002'}, {1: '2 may 2003'}]
>>>
```

And you can define a helper function to get your `datetime` object:

```
>>> def to_date(dstring):
...     return datetime.datetime.strptime(dstring, '%d %b %Y')
...
>>> [{k:to_date(v.replace('okt','oct')) for k,v in d.items()} for d in li]
[{1: datetime.datetime(2002, 10, 1, 0, 0)}, {1: datetime.datetime(2003, 5, 2, 0, 0)}]
>>>
```

The equivalent neste-forloop for the comprehension construct would be:

```
>>> li2 = []
>>> for d in li:
...     temp = {}
...     for k,v in d.items():
...         temp[k] = to_date(v.replace('okt','oct'))
...     li2.append(temp)
...
>>> li2
[{1: datetime.datetime(2002, 10, 1, 0, 0)}, {1: datetime.datetime(2003, 5, 2, 0, 0)}]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
' '.join(['October', '20', '2000'])
```

is what you want. `string.join(list)` joins each element of an array separated by a string. In this case, you can plug in your array separated by a space.

As for a better way to replace okt with oct, you can use this as the first line of your loop and get rid of the replace function:

```
a=item[1].replace('okt', 'oct').split()
```

EDIT (array->list): Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: `array` is a bad name. Almost certainly, you are working with a `list`.

Comment: `list` is an even *worse* name, because it shadows the built-in function, `list`.

Comment: What about spaces? I need the answer like this:  1 Oct 2002. This problem happened in the middle of webscraping. All the dates are fine except those have Okt and Maj, which I need to take care of. But I have to keep the format. The format is: there is space between them.

Comment: The spaces will be added in the middle if you run `'  '.join([something])`. Make sure there is a space in the string.

Comment: Perfect it worked. :-) But is there any better way than I used  to replace Okt by Oct in the dictionary.

Comment: Sure, you can run `a=item[1].replace('okt', 'oct').split()`. Then you won't need the replace function.